# Spartacus extend or override the PageType enum from cms.model

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I have encountered a Spartacus problem.

To be short I need to either override or extend the PageType enum from cms.model. It currently has four enum values (content, product, category, catalog) and I need to add a fifth (order).

Comment: That is not simple or easy, as the page types are fundamentally defined in the SAP Commerce system rather than Spartacus.  It would be unusual to do this & there may be a better way to handle the basic requirement.  Perhaps it would be better if you elaborated what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You have to augment enum, like this:

```
declare module '@spartacus/core' {
  enum PageType {
    NEW_PAGE_TYPE = 'NewPageType',
  }
}

(PageType as any)['NEW_PAGE_TYPE'] = 'NewPageType';
```

When using it, if it throws an error that it is not assignable to type PageType, then you can do this:

```
PageType.NEW_PAGE_TYPE as PageType
```

Documentation link:
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/type-augmentation/#augmenting-enums

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to create an Order page. There is an OOTB Order page which is an instance of ContentPage (content PageType). See OOTB `cms-responsive-content_en.impex` from OOTB storefronts (e.g. apparel, electronics). You can re-configure that instead.